# Shiftout only handles one shift register at a time

Tags: arduino-uno, shift-register, led-matrix

I am making a 7x10 led matrix and I am having problems with the shiftout function. It is only able to show me the output in one shiftout register at a time. How can I fix it?
[image]

For example:

```
void setup(){
    // PORTB as output.
    // Pin 13: Clock 74HC595
    // Pin 12: Latch
    // Pin 11: Data
    // Pin 10: Reset
    // Pin 9: Clock CD4017
    DDRB = 0b111111;
    // Makes sure the 4017 value is 0.
    PORTB = 0b100;
    delayMicroseconds(5);
    PORTB = 0;
}

void loop(){
  shiftOut(11, 13, LSBFIRST, 0b1000111101);
  PORTB = 0b10000;
  delayMicroseconds(800);
  PORTB = 0;
  delay(10000);
}
```

This is the output it produces:

[image]

But with numbers of 8 bits or less the output is displayed correctly.

shiftOut(11, 13, LSBFIRST, 0b10001111);
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shiftOut` works on bytes. To do more than one byte you have to do more than one `shiftOut`. Also you have to take note of the bit ordering. You should shift the most significant bit first, not the least.

For example, this:

```cpp
  shiftOut(11, 13, LSBFIRST, 0b1000111101);
```

should be:

```cpp
  shiftOut(11, 13, MSBFIRST, 0b10);
  shiftOut(11, 13, MSBFIRST, 0b00111101);
```

Comment: The same thing still happens, in this case only the sixth led of the first row lights up.

Comment: What could it be? :(

Comment: I think it's the bit ordering that is wrong. Use MSBFIRST and not LSBFIRST?

Comment: It still does not work correctly, in this case the output on the LEDs is 1011110000. Could it be the simulator?

Comment: I just finished making my board, I loaded a programming with two shiftout and the output was displayed correctly, it is a problem of the simulator. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the implementation of `shiftOut()` (you can find it where you installed the Arduino IDE in the file `hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_shift.c`):

```
void shiftOut(uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t clockPin, uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val)
{
  uint8_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {
    if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST) {
      digitalWrite(dataPin, val & 1);
      val >>= 1;
    } else {
      digitalWrite(dataPin, (val & 128) != 0);
      val <<= 1;
    }

    digitalWrite(clockPin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);
  }
}
```

Do you see, that the value (parameter `val`) is of type `uint8_t`, so only 1 byte big? And do you see, that the for loop only counts to 8 (one iteration for each bit in a byte)? This means, that the `shiftOut()` function only handles one byte at a time. When you want to shift out more bits than 8, you need to call it repeatedly.

In your first example the code behaves accordingly. The provided data gets cast to `uint8_t`, cutting away the upper 2 bits.

Comment: I tried sending two shiftout but still the same thing happens :/

Comment: Could it be the simulator?

Comment: Yes, it might be, that the simulator doesn't handle the output of additional shift data to the next shift register. Though that is something, that only the creator of the simulator software can answer you.

Comment: I just finished making my board, I loaded a programming with two shiftout and the output was displayed correctly, it is a problem of the simulator. Thanks for the help.